# Select tickers based on their sector only

Tags: python, grouping

I have only two weeks experience with Python, my problem isn't that hard though, thank you for your help. I have a data frame of the s&p 500 constituents. I would like to organize it by sector.

> So how can I select the companies ticker that are in the Health Care sector only for instance? Please find a sample of my data frame below.

I tried with `pd.groupby()`, but I can only select the columns name.

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `==`:

```
>>> df
                   Security Symbol SEC filings             GICS Sector
0  Agilent Technologies Inc      A     reports             Health Care
1   American Airlines Group    AAL     reports             Industrials
2        Advance Auto Parts    AAP     reports  Consumer Discretionary
3                Apple Inc.   AAPL     reports  Information Technology
4               AbbVie Inc.   ABBV     reports             Health Care
>>> df.loc[df['GICS Sector'] == 'Health Care']
                   Security Symbol SEC filings  GICS Sector
0  Agilent Technologies Inc      A     reports  Health Care
4               AbbVie Inc.   ABBV     reports  Health Care
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I have tried to set the Sector column as index and execute `df[df=="Health Care"]`. But didn't work as expected...

Comment: Did you use `GICS Sector` as that is the name of the column in your example?

Comment: The solution you gave me works perfectly. It gives me the desired output. However, before that, when I was trying things by myself, I have done the following: `sp500 = pd.read_excel('SP500_Constituents_Updated.xlsx', index_col="GICS Sector")`, then `sp500[sp500=="Health Care"]`. But didn't work as expected..

Comment: `sp500` is the name of the data frame, therefore you need to specify a specific column within it before using `==`.

Comment: Yes correct. I don't know why I thought by setting GICS Sector as index Python will understand. :) Thank you again.